# How to fix tinyMCE getting stuck on iPad with canvas below it?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, canvas, tinymce

I am having a sandwich of canvas and tinymce rich text editor. Now there are two modes, one is to draw on canvas and one is to write text on tinymce.

When on draw mode then canvas layer comes upwards and tinymce goes below this canvas layer and when on text mode vice-versa happens using z-index.

When I start typing on iPad with canvas layer below text layer it works fine until I move the cursor upwards by touching my iPad screen. As soon as I does that editor gets stuck and to make editor work again I have to hide my iPad browser's keypad and then touch again on editor.

There is one more thing that as soon as I remove canvas from html and there is only one single layer of tinymce then things works perfectly as expected however it works fine on normal pc browser without any issue.

I tried to debug and noticed z-index change as expected and when stuck our code does not even detect keypress events on tinyMCE with ipad.

Any idea what could be the possible reason or fix?

Comment: iPad and rtes are causing head-aches :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report on the TinyMCE site:
http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5447

I changed the defaultNativeHandler code in tiny_mce_src.js as was suggested in the thread, but it didn't resolve the problems I'm seeing (using python-django 1.5.1b4).

Comment: thanks for input but this is more like a comment than a solution.